# zip and archive all files in a specified folder

Tags: powershell, zip, 7zip

I am trying to zip all the sales data we receive daily and archive after we are done processing the files and rename the zip file as `saletransactions_mmddyyyy.zip`. The script I have is trying to zip each individual file. How do I change it all the files into one zip file.

```cs
$srcPath = "\\networkshare\test\sale"
$destPath = "\\networkshare\test\sale\archive\"
$ext = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcPath | Where-Object { ($_.Extension -eq ".txt") }

Set-Alias sz "\\networkshare\test\7z.exe"

foreach ($file in $ext) {
  $name = $file.Name
  $directory = $file.DirectoryName
  $zipfile = $name.Replace(".txt", ".7z")
  sz a -t7z "$destPath\$($file.BaseName).zip" $file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the last line of your code, here

```
sz a -t7z "$destPath\$($file.basename).zip" $file
```

In this line, you're telling 7Zip to add a file to a zip archive which is to be named the same as the file you're adding. That means the output zip will always be the same as the name of the file, which is why you're getting one zip file per input file.

If you'd like to add them all to a monthly archive instead, first define the name of the output file somewhere at the top of your code, like this.

```
$month = "03_2017"
```

Then, change the last line to this, and you'll be good to go.

```
7z a -t7z $destPath\$month.zip" $file
```